Is there a way I can use npm with the direct source code rather than minified/bundled code?
I want to use npm and JavaScript (or TypeScript) 3rd party libraries directly from the source code.
For example, in Python, I can go directly into the source code make changes in them and see it directly reflected in my application. I want the same functionality with JavaScript because this helps me understand what's going on with my 3rd party dependencies.

In the node_modules folder you can often find the complete source code of your npm modules, they are often not minified. Minification only happens after the build phase. But it's not recommended to edit node_modules because it can be overwritten by npm install. You can also find the source code on the github page of the npm module.

It depends. With some libraries the source code will also be runnable (if the build process is just minification and/or uglification) but those that need transpilation (e.g. TypeScript source) won't. If the maintainers ship source maps your tools may be able to use those for debugging.

If I understand your question correctly, https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-link is the key of that.
I have my own npm package and without publishing it, I can use the changes directly with only build package while using with npm-link

Thanks everyone, I'll look into npm-link. Also, it's not recommended but I won't be shipping my local node_modules to production. yes, but I also want the ability to change it's source code, for example to see if there's a bug in the 3rd party library.

Npm link isn't really a requirement, you can replace a dep in node_modules with a symlink with the same effect. And you can change anything directly in node_modules for debugging purposes, even if it's bundled it's still readable

u can fork the package and use npm link

I have found the easiest way is to:

Fork the npm module's repo (most modules have a link to the source code.)
Make the desired changes to the package.
(Some packages may require a build step. Check the readme/package.json)
Add the module via your fork's github url (instead of the package name)

https://gitpkg.vercel.app/ helps get the appropriate url to npm install for a certain folder/commit.

It is also possible to monkey-patch the module from the node_modules folder.
The main property of package.json determines what is loaded when a package is imported (is it from a built file in a dist folder? Just a JS source file?)
Editing the files in node_modules will have immediate effect, but may be overridden by future npm commands. Something like patch-package may help make your changes more permanent.

Related references:

How to install an npm package from GitHub directly
monkey patching at the npm package level?


If you want to use a package from npm in a webapp, but you don't want to go through the hassle of downloading and minifying and all that, you can use unpkg.com directly with plain javascript.
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react"></script>

My question is a bit different from what you're suggesting.
